# Finding a Matrix from Determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

I've stumbled upon this problem on my homework, and I have no clue how to do it, and haven't found any help online:

[image]

If I'm understanding this correctly, then $det(M) = ad - cb + eh - gf$ ?
What I don't get is how to find M from knowing this information.

Are there any suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: The $1\times 1$ matrix with entry $ad-cb+eh-gf$ has the desired determinant.  Admittedly, this is probably not what they're looking for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $\det(M)=ad-bc+eh-fg=(ad+eh)\times1-(bc+fg)\times1$ (assuming M is required to be 2x2, otherwise the trivial example by Jared in the comments would suffice)

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear what the dimension of $M$ should be, but here is a start to a solution where $M$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix:

$$\begin{pmatrix}a&??\\1&d\end{pmatrix}$$

Try to finish it from here (i.e., find what goes in the entry labeled $??$).